# Load page content to variable

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

**Good day.**

*I never really got a good hand at JavaScript, therefore this unusual and simple question.*

How can i load a page content to a JavaScript variable, with the least amount of code, no framework, and the less impact possible on performance?

**Thanks.**

---

**EDIT**

Sorry guys. I forgot to mention: Get the page content from the specified url to a JS var.

---

**Following [Brendan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501131/brendan) [Suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229043/load-page-content-to-variable/4229141#4229141)**

I had already seen Brendan alternative elsewhere and tried it, but it didn't work at the time, and it doesn't work now. Meanwhile Firebug and the Browsers tested (IE8 and FF) don't report any error. So whats wrong?

Comment: Help us out - Do you mean the content of the CURRENT page?

Comment: If you are looking to access a different page, this may be useful: http://www.xul.fr/ajax/responseHTML-attribute.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a modified version of an example you can find at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_http.asp).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc(theURL)
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, SeaMonkey
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", theURL, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

So just make "example.html" be any sort of path (relative or absolute) to the page you want to load, and `xmlhttp.responseText` will be a string containing the response content. You can also use `xmlhttp.responseXML` if you want it to be stored as a traversable XML document. Anyway, just assign either of those to a variable of your choice, and you will have it!

Note that 'loadXMLDoc' does not return anything directly but defines one of its members ('onreadystatechange') to do that job, and to does it only in certain condition (readyState and status). Conclusion - do not assign the output of this function to any var. Rather do something like:

```
var xmlhttp=false;
loadXMLDoc('http://myhost/mycontent.htmlpart');
if(xmlhttp==false){ /* set timeout or alert() */ }
else { /* assign `xmlhttp.responseText` to some var */ }
```

Without that, all one can see is 'undefined'...

Comment: I tried that, with http: //google.com instead. No luck, no console errors.

Comment: Note that the URL has to be within the same domain otherwise you will get security errors (thats why google.com doesnt work). See the specs here: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method

Comment: @WSkid: Thanks. I didn't knew that, so how i can i use it for urls outside my domain?

Comment: @Fabio : Query your server-side code to get that external data for you. Eg. Make  "getGoogle.php" return data from "google.com" and set the content-type as "application/html" in your server-side script.

Comment: @conqenator: Unfortunately i can only use JavaScript. There is any way just using JS?

Answer (score 12):

To get everything inside the html tags:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
var text = html.innerHTML;
```

Then you can wrap that in html tags.  Doesn't capture doctype or anything else you'd have outside the html tags, but it's a quick way to grab most of the content.

Comment: +1. If no header information is needed than this works for body aswell. It works even for every tag that's unique.

Comment: Good point, it's definitely the quick and dirty way of grabbing a bunch of html from where ever you need it

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention. I need to get the content from another page. Not the one Javascript is running.

Comment: Do not forget about this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194231

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is really old now, but I have had the same issue with trying to get the page contents into a variable, but have finally figured out a way in Javascript :D (With some help from the internet ...)

So here it goes ...

I made a function with a callback to get a desired page:

```
function getPageContents(callback,url,params) {
    http=new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(params!=null) {
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    } else {
        http.open("GET", url, true);
    }
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            callback(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
}
```

Note that I have made it in such a way, that it wont accept GET paramaters. This is intentional, as I have no need to use GET for my application. If params are set, these will be sent as POST.

Then to use the function, lets say I want to post a name to `findpersoninfo.php` which will output a JSON array of that persons info, I can do this:

```
getPageContents(function(result) {
    personinfo=JSON.parse(result);
    //Now I can do anything here with the personinfo array
},'http://localhost/findpersoniinfo.php','fname=stretch&lname=wright')
```

Taking it a step further, you can nest this inside another function, lets call it `getPersonInfo()`:

```
function getPersonInfo(fname,lname) {
    getPageContents(function(result) {
        personinfo=JSON.parse(result);
        //Now I can do anything here with the personinfo array
    },'http://localhost/findpersoninfo.php','fname='+fname+'&lname='+lname)
}
```

Of course, my knowledge of Javascript is still in it's infancy, and welcome any constructive feedback :D

Comment: this is the better answer.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution to download JSON data from a url like `/v1/data?format=json`:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/v1/data?format=json", false);
xmlhttp.send();
var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```