# How to convert a jQuery load method to plain javascript, without added libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this working **ajax** code:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#post-list a').click(function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#ajax-div').load(url+ " #post");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

How do I convert it to plain JavaScript without jQuery, or any other libraries?
I believe it has something to do with **XMLHttpRequest**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229043/load-page-content-to-variable

Comment: i don't really know JavaScript, just know how to search, i have seen the script you have shared, but have no idea how to target the clickable element (#post-list a), and how to get only a the #post (and its content) from the responseText.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming "post-list a" is the anchor tag you can do:

```js
document.getElementById('post-list a').addEventListener('click',function(){
    window.location.href = this.href;
})
```

Comment: this just opens the link, without ajax, without filtering the element content that i want.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function to call other page, like this:

```
function call(){

}
```

add this function like `onclick` in your `<button>` or `<a>`