# Ajax: load several pages content to a variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

Based on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229043/load-page-content-to-variable), I've tried to call the function from within a for loop to load the content of some pages in my local domain, but I only get the result for the first page, and this only when I comment the for line.
Here's my code:

```
    function ready()
{
    var from = 0, to = sites.length;
    var xmlhttp=false;
    var content = '';

    for(from; from < to; from++)
    {
        loadDoc(sites[from]);
        if(xmlhttp==false)
        {
            setTimeout(loadDoc(pages[from]), 1000);  //try every sec.
        }
        else
        { content = xmlhttp.responseText;}
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong/missing? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**First:** from what I see in your code,you are re-assigning new data to the *"content"* variable in every iteration (which means that instead of accumulating each iteration's data, it re-write it self in every iteration by the latest xmlhttp.responseText)

If you wish to accumulate all contents in one single variable (as a string) then you should use variable addition like this:

```
content += xmlhttp.responseText;
```

In case you want to store all responses in a single variable but as an array (which you can later iterate for each individual content response) you can use array addition, define an empty array:

```
var contentList = [];
```

and push a new item into it in every iteration:

```
contentList.push(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

I hope it helps a bit