# How to read the source of another webpage - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Are there any ways to read the html from another website using javascript? In java you can just do this:

```
URL url = URL("https://google.com")
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream())
```

and then save it to a string by doing this:

```
String html = ""
while(scanner.hasNext()) html += scanner.nextLine() + "\n"
```

but i haven't found any easy ways to do this in (plain) javascript. Are there even any? I've tried the iframe trick, but a lot of pages block it these days, including google drive, which is the page i want to get the html from.

Comment: Not from another origin - it is not "a lot of pages block" it is ALL pages block acces not from the same origin or when CORS is not enabled

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229043/load-page-content-to-variable

Comment: @aurelius that would not work at all

Comment: Please perform a [minimum of research](https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript+access+OR+read+another+webpage+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: A solution is for you to write a proxy that returns your client the source of a site you read using JAVA on the server