# Is it possible to set the value property of a <textarea> tag to be the source code of an html file?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I want to know if it is possible to set the value property of a <textarea> tag to be set to the HTML of a webpage.

I'm trying to set the value to be equal to the HTML of the local file "./file.html".

```
document.getElementById("textareaTag").value = ;
```

Since I'm new to JavaScript,  I don't have a solution, even though there probably is one. Can anyone help me?

NOTE: Some digging around makes it look like it might be possible to accomplish this with a window.open() command. Would it work? If so, how?

Comment: check appendchild and innerhtml

Answer (score 0):

You can place an HTML file into a JS variable by this method:

> [Load page content to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229043/load-page-content-to-variable)

And then put variable into textarea.
Although in textarea you can't show html tags and you need a WYSIWYG rich text editor like CKEditor.

Comment: So is it not possible to get data from locally stored files? I want to be able to run the webpage offline.

Comment: If you want to run it offline, you can make your website a PWA.

Comment: That's why it's stored locally - my device lets me run HTML files stored on my device.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I'll try my best to answer.</sub>

You can set the text inside of a `<textarea>` using the `.innerHTML` property, as the `textarea` tag has an opening and closing tag.

Use the code below:

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").innerHTML = "Textarea!";
```

---

**EDIT:** Editing the text on a different webpage is a security risk.

Comment: What I'm asking is, can you set the value (in your example "Textarea!") to be the inner HTML of a _separate webpage_ that is stored locally _on your device_?

Comment: Not that I know of. It might be a security risk.

Comment: OK, well, thanks for helping anyways.